# How best to animate to a moving target float value in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, osmdroid

Given a flow of Float values (in this specific case these float values are between 0f and 360f and represent the orientation of an Android device or direction of travel) I want to change the orientation of a map (OSMDroid Map).

However when I update the maps orientation directly with the values as they are provided to me via using a SensorEventListener, the result is ugly as the map orientation does not smoothly animate between the orientation values.

I am already cleaning up the Orientation values from the sensor using a LowPassFilter, but now I want to improve the logic further by animating between the values as they come in by having a moving target the orientation of the map will try to reach.

Experimenting with ValueAnimator does not appear to solve my problem here, as the animations are set to a fixed duration, or repeat and I cannot change my target value dynamically.

I am effectively looking for a solution which would do the same as Jetpack Composes's .animate*AsState(), but also accounting for rotating around 360f -> 0f in a way that does not cause the map to have to animate from 360 down to 0 through values 270, 180 etc.

Here is the class where I am trying to achieve this with all relevant code included:

```kotlin
class MapOrientationController(private val mapView: MapView) : LocationListener, SensorEventListener {
    val targetOrientation: Flow<Float> = /* .. existing logic to get current device orientation or direction of travel if moving .. */

    fun setMapOrientation(orientation: Float) {
        mapView.mapOrientation = orientation
    }

    fun start() {
        /* .. existing logic to start listening to location updates/ sensors .. */

        TODO("Implement logic to animate between current map orientation and target orientation")
    }

    fun stop() {
        /* .. existing logic to stop listening to location updates/ sensors .. */

        TODO("Implement logic to stop animating between current map orientation and target orientation")
    }
    
    /* .. Override methods relating to getting orientation .. */
}
```